# How to calculate row_cache_size_in_mb and key_cache_size_in_mb in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, jvm, heap-memory, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0

I have a cluster with 3 DC with 3,3 and 1 nodes respectively. I want to tune the cluster for better performance and hence want to enable row_cache and set its size in cassandra.yaml but don't know how to calculate its size. I used the utility https://github.com/joaquincasares/heap-calculator but could not get the script avg_row_size_calculator is not supported with the cassandra version 3.0.
Is there any formula or utility to calculate the row_cache_size and key_cache_size? 
Total available memory per node is 32G and MAX_HEAP_SIZE is 14G.